# QTcpSocket memory leaking

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qtnetwork

I have a client-server application setup using QTcpServer and QTcpSockets and seem to have some huge memory leaks. I'm wondering if the problem is in my use of Qt's sockets because I have just set up a simple test application and after sending 250,000,000 messages in a loop my client rises up to 75 meg. It seems that if I have several million messages, I see 300+ MB of memory used in my client.

This doesn't seem right to me, as I keep sending messages the memory just keeps on rising!

So should I expect my app to constantly rise in memory given the following code on a connected socket. If this socket is left open I'm going to quickly run out of memory. Am I missing something?

```
if (socket && socket->isOpen())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 25000000; ++i) {
        QString str = "test";
        socket->write(str.toStdString().c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing/assigning your socket variable?  Add more code if you can.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected because you are potentially buffering a large amount of data. This is an async API due to the Qt event loop, so you should wait for the write when the program is ready for that.

You can use the `void QIODevice::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes) [signal]` signal to continue the writing. If you use the async API this way, you will avoid the large memory consumption.

Comment: I tired writing the messages as described above and agree that with it being buffered it will increase in memory. What I failed to add though was that if I then wait for a period of time with the event loop running (and thus sending the messages), then send (or rather buffer) another bunch of messages I see the memory go double. If i wait again and then send some more, the memory goes up yet again. As the messages are sent, the size of the buffer surely decreases?

Comment: @user1818822: did you connect your writing operation as a slot to the aforementioned signal? Then, it will not happen anymore.

Comment: @user1818822: have you figured out?

Comment: I see a similar problem, but with multiple connection. I DeleteLater all the QTcpSocket, but still, when I run 500 connection simultaneously the memory keep increasing every time I shot over another 500 connection. I dont think I have memory leak, I just think it is a bug in the buffer management of the Classes.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. With hundreds o connections I see memory increasing considerably. Did you solve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The socket is an internally buffered `QIODevice`, and whatever you've written to it gets buffered until the network stack can actually send it out. What you see is expected behavior. The `write()` is *not* a blocking operation, and anyway you should *never ever* do blocking operations in your GUI thread, unless you think users really enjoy applications with dead user interface.

Perhaps you want to put your writing in a slot that gets informed of the socket's progress? The sockets are all `QIODevice`. Look there for the useful signals, `bytesWritten()` for example. It's customary to defer writing unless the value returned by `bytesToWrite()` is below a set threshold. Your writing slot could begin like so:

```
// more than 2 pages worth of stuff still to send, we abstain
if (socket->bytesToWrite() > 1<<13) return;
```

Nitpick: The `toStdString()` is completely grauituous. You should be using:

```
socket->write(str.toUtf8().constData());
```

Never mind that for such testing, you can trivially create an array of bytes without using a string at all:

```
const QByteArray testData(1000, ' '); // a 1000 spaces
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) socket->write(testData);
```