# QTcpSocket "leaks" memory

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qtcpsocket

I need help with `QTcpSocket`'s rising memory.

Of course I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264500/qt-c-qtcpsocket-causes-memory-leak-not-sure-why), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256495/qtcpsocket-memory-leak) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164770/qtcpsocket-memory-leaking), but unfortunately they are not solving this issue for me.

I wrote a simple class which encapsulates `QTcpSocket`:

```
#include "GWCommunicator.h"

GWCommunicator::GWCommunicator() {
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
}

    bool GWCommunicator::send(const char *data, qint64 size) {
        socket->write(data, size);
        return socket->waitForBytesWritten();
    }

    GWCommunicator::~GWCommunicator() {
        delete socket;
    }

    bool GWCommunicator::connectToServer() {
        socket->connectToHost(SERVERIP, 6498, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        return socket->waitForConnected();
    }

    bool GWCommunicator::disconnectFromServer() {
        socket->disconnectFromHost();
        return socket->waitForDisconnected();
    }
```

Where `socket` is `QTcpSocket*` declared as a private field in header file.

In the manner of functionality, everything is fine. But this socket consumes more and more memmory with each message sent. It is not an actual leak, but some kind of buffering (which correspond with QIODevice documentation - note for QTcpSocket). Docs also says that you can use Unbuffered mode when opening device. But this is not posible in QTcpSocket:

> Note: TCP sockets cannot be opened in QIODevice::Unbuffered mode.

How should I avoid it? I understood that `waitForBytesWritten()` should do it but it obviously does not.

main class looks like this:

```
#include "GWCommunicator.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

GWCommunicator *communicator;

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/) {
    communicator = new GWCommunicator();
    communicator->connectToServer();

    string stdstr("Hello world");
    const char* str = stdstr.c_str();
    int count = 0;
    int length = stdstr.size();

    while (count++ < 10000) {
        communicator->send(str, length);
    }

    communicator->disconnectFromServer();
    delete communicator;
    return 0;
}
```

And my header file is following.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>

#ifndef GWCOMMUNICATOR_H
#define GWCOMMUNICATOR_H

#define SERVERIP "127.0.0.1"

class GWCommunicator : private QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GWCommunicator();
    ~GWCommunicator();
    bool connectToServer();
    bool disconnectFromServer();
    bool send(const char *datam, qint64 size);

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif  /* GWCOMMUNICATOR_H */
```

Comment: Are you certain that the memory leak is caused by `QTcpSocket`, and not by your code? For example, you might have forgotten to deallocate `const char *data` that you pass to `GWCommunicator::send()`, or something like that. To check that `QTcpSocket` does leak, try creating a test program that only writes to a socket, and then start it and read its output, and see if it increases its memory. If it does, post **that test program** as a SSCCE. Also I noticed that Java tag in your user profile, if you are primarily a Java programmer, it is very likely you have forgotten to deallocate something.

Comment: if you pass a parent to the constructor of socket you don't need to `delete` it, as is you have a double delete

Comment: @ratchetfreak good point, I didn't notice

Comment: @sashoalm yes I am sure. I'm using valgrind for watching leaks, but there is none. The app has 500KB allocated ... then it grows ove 100MB and when I delete my GWCommunicator, than it fall again to 500K. So it has to be something inside this socket. There is nothing else in this class or header.

Comment: @Kousalik Still, did you create a SSCCE and test it? If so, post it.

Comment: @sashoalm I'm not sure how, you need an server against it. But there is nothing else. Send is just called thousand times with constant characters from main method within a loop and then the GWCommunicator object is deleted. No more new/delete. Only one object, one new, one delete. And it grows only by calling my posted send method. Nothing else is in the loop.

Comment: @sashoalm I added what I could.

Comment: @Kousalik Ah, then there is no error, only the illusion of a bug. The data is indeed buffered, but it will be removed from the buffer as soon as it is read from the socket. If you simply "send" data that is never read by the other side of the connection, it accumulates of course, waiting. Can you reproduce a leak if the data is actually being read? Try with `netcat` it's a free tool.

Comment: @ratchetfreak "if you pass a parent to the constructor of socket you don't need to delete" That's not quite correct. The deletion is safe, if redunant, *as long as the parent exists*. If the parent has ceased to exist, then indeed the deletion is an error, known as double delete.

Comment: @Kousalik "I'm not sure how, you need an server against it." This is Qt. A TCP server is 20-30 lines of code. You have to learn how to prepare minimal test cases.

Comment: How do you know that you have a memory leak? What tool did you used? How do you know that memory consumption grows every time you send something through a socket? What about server response - I don't see any reading in your code?

Comment: @MarekR hi you are right, there are many received data ready to read from the servers response! bytesAvailable return pretty high number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as pointed out by @MarekR, the reason for this "leak" is no reading from the socket. So the QTcpSocket is buffering responses from server. This allocated memmory is released after retreiving incoming data from socket.

Answer (score 0):

**It takes two to tango.** You write into the socket all the while ignoring whether the other end of the connection has read anything from said socket.

**You are solely responsible for the growth of the write buffer.** You should check the write buffer size (available via `bytesToWrite`) and *cease* writing to the socket if it's past some threshold that you feel comfortable about.

There's absolutely no magic to it: you, and only you, make that buffer grow.

The growth of the write buffer, as indicated by `bytesToWrite` is an indication that you're writing faster than the other side reads the data. There can be various reasons for that, such as:

- slow communications channel,
- badly implemented server.

Comment: The server is Java based production-grade application which works perfectly fine and receives immediatelly every message I send to it. I can wait as long as I want in my app but the buffer stays full. Any further idea ? I also doublechecked the bytesToWrite and its zero.